# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException with swift

Tags: ios, swift3

i am setting up a userdefualt integer and when i segue to the page the app crashes. It shows the appDelegate with it says " Thread 1: signal SIGBART" and in the debugger it says "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Her is my code, please help me find the error:

```
class home: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var fiveth1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var iron1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gold1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ships1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var empires1: UIWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var webViewG: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let htmlPath1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WebViewContent2", ofType: "html")
    let htmlURL1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath1!)
    let html1 = try? Data(contentsOf: htmlURL1)

    self.webViewG.load(html1!, mimeType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: htmlURL1.deletingLastPathComponent())


    if (Fiveth.value(forKey: "Fiveth") != nil){
        fiveth = Fiveth.value(forKey: "Fiveth") as! NSInteger!
        fiveth1.text = NSString(format: "Fiveth: %i", fiveth) as String
    }

    fiveth1.text = "\(Fiveth)"
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the console output, is there any additional information? At the start of the log, there might be a description of what's causing the issue.

Comment: @nathan i added in a screenshot, does this help?

Comment: Can you scroll up in the console? At the top of the call stack there should be a more detailed description of the error.

Comment: @nathan i added another picture

Comment: Great! I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have an `NSUnknownKeyException` for the key 'empires'. This is usually caused by an outlet in the Storyboard that doesn't match the name in code. You most likely created an outlet when the variable was called `empires` before you re-named it to `empires1`.

To fix this, disconnect and re-connect the outlet in the storyboard.

Comment: That is exactly what happened, thanks for catching my mistake!

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct so others in the future can benefit from it as well. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Feel free to search first next time. This has been asked and answered hundreds of times already.